# node.js remove event listener nested inside a event listener

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const globalInput = new Promise(resolve => {
            function callback(msg) {
                client.off('message', (msg) => callback(msg));
                resolve(msg.content);
            }
            client.on('message', (msg) => callback(msg));
        });
```

Here I've used the message event emitter to send the message contents back in a resolved promise, and I've used client.off. However even after this, I still get the 11 event listeners attached to client warning. Where am I going wrong? And yes this is the only variable that actually attaches the event emitter.

Comment: You are passing new anonymous function as callback to each listen and remove events, you need pass exact same function to remove listener.
`client.on('message', callback)` `client.off('message', callback)`. Anyway use `.once` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.off()` requires that you pass it the identical function reference (not a different function that is an identical copy).  So, you can fix your code by making the first message handler be a separate local function that you can then refer to in both `.on()` and `.off()`:

```
    const globalInput = new Promise(resolve => {
        function handler(msg) {
             client.off('message', handler);
             resolve(msg.content);
        }
        client.on('message', handler);
    });
```

FYI, you can also use [`.once()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#emitteronceeventname-listener) and it will handle the removal for you automatically.

```
    const globalInput = new Promise(resolve => {
        client.once('message', msg => {
            resolve(msg.content);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about .once()